# How to retrieve all distinct values of attribute "title" from LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to get all the distinct values of a field from LDAP by Java. But I don't know how to do it.

There is an attribute in LDAP called "title". I would like to get all the distinct values of that field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: His question history is abysmal. It's a bunch of vague questions and 30% of them are negative.

Answer (score 4):

There is no LDAP API that supports that directly, like say SELECT DISTINCT in SQL. You will have to retrieve all the values and filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve attributes from an LDAP directory server database, the LDAP client must connect to the server, establish an authentication state with the BIND request, and transmit a search request to the server, and interpret the response. A search request is composed of at a minimum:

- a base object where the search above which entries are not returned
- a scope, either the base object itself (base), one-level subordinate
  to the base object, or whole subtree (all objects subordinate to the base object
- a filter which constrains the responses
- a list of attribute to retrieve from the entries that matched the search request parameters.

To retrieve all attributes with an alias of `title` use the following filter: `(title=*)` with an appropriate base object and scope described above. The LDAP directory server will return all objects that have a `title` attribute. If `title` is multi-valued, object might contain more than one `title`. The LDAP client is responsible for ordering the results. There is no `SELECT DISTINCT` facility. If the number of entries with a `title` attribute too large for the client, the client can use the Simple Paged Results Request Control to control the rate at which entries are returned from the LDAP Directory Server.

Do not use JNDI (java.naming.*) for new code. Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) instead.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)
- [Sample code](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code)